# How do I comment out a line in my .curlrc?

Tags: curl

I frequently have to switch between two different auth token request headers, that I keep in my `.curlrc` as such:

```
-H "X-Auth-Token: 12345678-1234"
```

It would make my life easier, though, if I could just keep both in there, with one of them commented out when I'm using the other. Seemingly there's barely any documentation on how the `.curlrc` file is parsed, including on how commenting works or if there's any way to comment out lines at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, it seems like `.curlrc` follows the bash convention of using a hash character for comments:

```
-H "X-Auth-Token: 12345678-1234"
# -H "X-Auth-Token: asdfasdf-asdf"
```

The above will only pass the numerical auth token.

Inlining comments is also possible:

```
-H "X-Auth-Token: 12345678-1234"  # The other token is asdfasdf-asdf
```